# Avoid Request user each time for permission (and login) before posting

Tags: android, facebook

The concept of my app to request user to login using Facebook for first time, and once user logged-in, he could send messages and these message will posted to user facebook wall.

the issue is, suppose user logged-in today, and few days, use would like to send message.
Now, when I call  `Session.getActiveSession()` it will return null, and I have again to reopen session which involve again asking permission from user and presenting facebook login screen.

Hence, I wonder if there away to save session, so that once user login once, no need to relogin again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions by default are saved in a token cache (stored in user preferences), unless you call session.closeAndClearTokenInformation somewhere in your code, it should be fine to "new" a session (it should get the cached data without any user interaction).